# fasttext assertion "counts.size() == osz_" failed

Tags: c++, fasttext

I am trying to use fasttext for text classification and I am training on a corpus of 850MB of texts on Windows, but I keep getting the following error:

```
assertion "counts.size() == osz_" failed: file "src/model.cc", line 206, function: void fasttext::Model::setTargetCounts(const std::vector<long int>&) Aborted (core dumped)
```

I checked the values of `counts.size()` and `osz_` and found that `counts.size = 2515626` and `osz_ = 300`. When I call `in.good()` on the input stream in `FastText::loadModel` i get 0, `in.fail()=1` and `in.eof()=1`.

I am using the following commands to train and test my model:

```
./fasttext supervised -input fasttextinput -output fasttextmodel -dim 300 -epoch 5 -minCount 5 -wordNgrams 2

./fasttext test fasttextmodel.bin fasttextinput
```

My input data is properly formatted according to the fasttext github page, so I am wondering if this is some failure of me or a bug.

Thanks for any support on this!

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/73 -- even if you think you have a lot of diskspace, remember that the output model can be very big, and running out of disk space can cause this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this thread:

As @Sixhobbits' pointed out the error was related to https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/73 (running out of disk space when saving the fastText supervised model)